Swiper-slider c cube-эффектом перекрывает чётные слайды
Ссылка на демо: cube-effect-error.netlify.app
Проблема со Swiper-Slider с cube-эффектом в layout-e - всего у меня 6 слайдов. С нечётными(1, 3, 5) слайдами можно взаимодействовать как обычно - выделять текст, нажимать на кнопки и тд. Но с чётными слайдами(2, 4, 6) - проблема, поверх них становится обёртка всего слайдера, закрывая собой сами слайды. И на них нельзя выделить текст, нажимать на кнопки и тд. Почему такое возможно, что такие проблемы именно с чётными слайдами??
Если поставить чётным слайдам большой z-index - это не помогает!
Как это исправить?
*Но нужно чтобы остался effect: cube
**демка грузится может долго
